# Associativity array in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, avro

I receive a `List<org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>` with the data contents as shown below (JSON notation used for clarity). How can I best hold these record types using Java?

**Record 1:**

```
   [
    {
      "serial_no" : "x",
      "data1" : "d"
    },
    {
     "serial_no" : "y",
     "data2" : "d2"
    },
    ............................MANY MORE
   ]
```

**Record 2:**

```
   [
    {
      "id":"x",
      "type":"A"
    },
    {
      "id" : "x",
      "type" : "B"
    },
    {
      "id" : "y",
      "type" : "A",
    },
    { 
      "id" : "y",
      "type" : "B"
    } 
   ]
```

As you see here, each `serial number` has two records in record2. `serial_no` in record1 is same as `id` in record2.

**My Goal is**:
       Fatsest way to find these two records.

**Solution I think**:

Create a map like

```
      map.put("x", [map.put("A",List), map.put("B",List)]);
```

But I feel like, its a complex structure. Because map contains list of maps`[each map is Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>]`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Each entries in records are [avro GenericRecord](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.Record.html)

Comment: A database would be fast.

Comment: Why is it downvoted? Didn't you get `blue color note` to specify the reason?

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if you are trying to parse JSON using Java. Why not use a specific library for that? 
Like the basic http://www.json.org/java/ or Google's https://github.com/google/gson

Otherwise, I do not think that the complex structure you are proposing is especially slow. You might want to design your own object class to hold the data if you think it is more efficient or easier to get to the data.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your question I assumed JSON was the format you received it in, sorry.

I would just create a wrapper for GenericRecord, or subclass it. Then add the methods that you need to extract the data, or make it `Comparable` for sorting.

Something along the lines of

```
public class MyRecord extends GenericRecord implements Comparable<MyRecord>
{
    // Determine the type
    public int getType()
    {
        if ( this.get( "id") != null )
            return 2;
        return 1;
    }
    // Add methods that allow you to retrieve the serial field from any of the two record types
    public String getId()
    {
        if ( this.get( "id") != null )
            return (String)this.get("id");
        return (String)this.get("serial_no");
    }

    // add comparator methods that will allow you to sort the list, compare based on Id, etc
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyRecord another) 
    {
        // Just a simple example
        return this.getId().compareTo( another.getId() );
    }
}
```

Comment: `gson` has two overloaded methods `toJson`, `fromJson`. Neither is useful in my case. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Do you receive the data as actual JSON?

Comment: No. It's List of [GenericRecord](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.Record.html)

Comment: This answer getting more attention. Can Upvoters help me?

Answer (score 1):

Define `class`es for repeated entries:

```
class SerialNoData {
    String serialNo;
    Object data;
}
```

and

```
class IdType {
    String id;
    String type;
}
```

; once parsed put the instances into arrays or `List`s to get the desired format.

Comment: You might want to prefer serialNo though.

Comment: I prefer this answer and let me try.

Answer (score 0):

How complex the map is doesn't really make a difference for the speed. Depending on the type of Map you use getting a list of records will be constant time (with a reasonably small overhead). Finding something in the sublists will then be O(n), since you need to iterate through the list and look at all the Maps.

Comment: No man. I need all the data in the map. I can filter it by first time. So it would be only one for loop then O(1) for all get operations

Comment: Then you really shouldn't be worried about the speed. Even with 10 million entries a hash map look up takes less than a tenth of a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Define following classes

```
class Serial{
 String serial-no;
 String data;
 List<IdType> idTypes;
}

class IdType{
 String id;
 String type;
}
```

After that you can use jackson or any kind of JSON processing library.

Comment: ``serial-no`` is not a valid identifier, and what's ``List<IdType> idTypes`` for?

Comment: Each record 1 has a multiple Records 2. That's why I used List to contain the Records2. I didn't understand "serial-no is not a valid identifier".

Comment: The author means that two corresponding ``IdType`` structures can be looked up with the serial number from ``Serial``. You can't put "-" in variables names, see [Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbuk/index.html)

Comment: I agreed with you. We can't use "-" in Java code. But we can map using any JSON library. (ex:- JsonMapping("serial-no"))